# Modelstate validate fields that are not required

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hidden-field

I have this problem where I need to validate a model with an ID, but I don't want to show the ID and I've tried to put it inside an hiddenfield.

Here's my model:

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class ObjInfo
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Variable declaration.
        /// </summary>

        public int m_Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obj Name is required.")]
        [MaxLength(75)]
        [Display(Name = "Obj Name")]
        public string m_Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Obj Symbol")]
        public string m_SymbolText { get; set; }
```

(...)
        }
    }

I've only put the problematic field and another field. There's also other non-relevant data in my model.

Now here's my "Create" view for this model:

```
@model MyApp.Models.ObjInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create New Obj</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>OBJ</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.m_Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.m_Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_Name)
        </div>

        (...)

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to obj list", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

So when I confirm the creation of this obj, the ModelState always returns false because of the ID provided, but I must not show this ID to the users and I need it for management issues.

Simply put, I think that there's no data in my hidden field. But it is not relevant because my BD will give the object a proper ID anyway. How can I solve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: As a complement of information, when the line:
if (ModelState.IsValid)
is hit, it is always false, all the fields of the object are keys, and thus it validates every field even though, like shown in my model up there, not all fields are marked as required.

Comment: just, remove hidden field. Because you dont need to set ID. ID initializing is job of DB.

Comment: you need id-hidden field in editing view...

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve the model in your action, use Bind to exclude `m_Id`:

```
public ActionResult Example([Bind(Exclude = "m_Id")] ObjInfo objInfo)
{ 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I will try this out when editing my objects. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this
public int? m_Id { get; set; }